# OR query in Algolia Web Interface

Tags: algolia

The documentation states that

> To OR refinements, you must use nested arrays. For example, to refine on “Business & Investing” books written by Jason Fried or David Heinemeier Hansson:

I can't get OR-queries to work in the Algolia web interface. Whenever I add a second parameter I get no results.

E.g. I want to have all entries with difficulties easy and medium:

> difficulty: medium, difficulty: easy

Is it currently not supported or do I use the wrong syntax?

Thank you!

Comment: Hello MrBr, any chance that the provided answer helped you? Let us know.

Comment: Well it helped int the way that I can't test OR-queries in the web interface.. but the code works fine..

Answer (score 1):

Currently you **cannot** use *disjunctive facets* (*OR filters*) **directly** from Algolia web interface; the syntax you're referring to is for *conjunctive facets* (*AND filters*).